# Why do transport containers for wafers open clockwise?

Tags: design, semiconductor

In the semiconductor industry and research, silicon wafers are transported in round plastic sample containers with a screw lid.

[image]

Other than any other screw top though, the lid always opens (releases) when turning in the *clockwise* direction, as opposed to e.g. a bottle cap that opens counterclockwise.

Is there a practical reason for this? Why are they made like this even by different brands?

Comment: Maybe the engineer behind this is left-handed ;) No I'm kidding but perhaps it's because it might prevent carelessness when opening the container (but I don't have proof of this but it's just my assumption).

Answer (score 1):

Normally all lids are provided with right-hand thread. In those cases where a layman could accidentally turn the lid on, left-hand thread is used to prevent this. An example are threaded connections for gas bottles. Probally this is agreed in the SEMI standards.

Comment: Left hand threads are used for gas so they are not connected to the wrong bottle - not a good idea to mix O2 and gas... the regulation control is different.